# Which AWS S3 API action will trigger which event type?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

There are several event types for S3 buckets which can trigger a lambda (or something else) which are listed [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/NotificationHowTo.html#supported-notification-event-types).

An event type correspond to a given action on a bucket. For instance the event type `s3:ObjectCreated:*` correspond to new object created event.

I would like to know which [S3 API Action](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_Operations.html) will trigger which event type.

For instance the `PutObject` Action will obviously trigger an `s3:ObjectCreated:*` event.
But for some other action, that's not obvious.

Is this well documented somewhere ? How can I find this information (without launching tests)?

Comment: Can you please be a bit more specific for which event types you consider it to be unclear? :)

Comment: I would like to find this information for all event types (I am doing some source code analysis to get call graphs).

Comment: I did some research in the API docs yesterday and everything pointed to the table you linked to, so I guess there's no direct Api-Call-action mapping that's publicly documented.  From the information in the table it seems to be possible to compile a table like that, that's why I'm wondering if there is anything unclear.

Comment: Thanks @Maurice . I have given a Feedback in the documentation asking for a clarification on this point.